# Vuejs - v-model with multiple checkboxes

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I have dynamic list of options which comes from api:

```
       <tr v-for="(option, index) in options">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="toggle" v-model="option.value" @click="toggleOption(option.id, index)">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="toggle">{{ option.value }}</label>
                </div>
```

Method:

```
 toggleOption(id, index) {
            let app = this;
            let option = this.options[index];
            app.loading = true;
            option.value = !option.value;
            axios.patch('/apiendoint' + id, option)
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.loading = false;
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {

                });
        }
```

When checkbox is clicked all checkboxes changes, if only one item comes from api everything is working. How to make to work it with multiple checkboxes?

Comment: I think you have a typo `v-model="options.value"` should be `v-model="option.value"`

Comment: oops, my bad, but this not solves problem.

Comment: You are missing `<td>` inside your `<tr>`...

Comment: Can you create a reproducible codepen or like that? It's not quite clear what do you need and what is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created basic working example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loading: false,
    options: [
      {id: 1, value: true},
      {id: 2, value: true},
      {id: 3, value: true},
    ]      
  },
  methods: {
    /*
      instead of passing `id` and `index`, just pass `option`
    */
    toggleOption(option) {
      let app = this;
      
      app.loading = true;
      option.value = !option.value;

      // REMOVE NEXT LINE to send ajax
      return;

      axios.patch('/apiendoint/' + option.id, option)
        .then(function (resp) {
          app.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(function (resp) {});
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <table>
    <tr v-for="(option, index) in options">
      <td>
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
          <input
            :id="'toggle-'+option.id"
            type="checkbox"
            class="custom-control-input"
            v-model="option.value"
            @click="toggleOption(option)"
          >
          <label class="custom-control-label" :for="'toggle-'+option.id">
            {{ option.value }}
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: that was solutions! Thanks! :-)